# Why do I get an error when installing react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I was trying to install react-bootstrap but I get the following message on the console.

[image]

I will appreciate any help since I'm new working with React

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

1. Make sure you have the latest npm (`npm install -g npm`).
2. Add an exception to your antivirus to ignore the `node_modules` folder in your project.
3. Ensure no other processes of node.js are running (check task manager)
4. If you are using Visual Studio Code, close it.
5. `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`
6. `npm install` and then `npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap`

Comment: i deleted node_modules folder but not package-lock.json an i was scratching my head for one hour. deleted both and able to install react-bootstrap thank @turchak
Could you tell me the reason why it is behaving like that?

Answer (score 1):

use `npm install react-bootstrap --force`

Comment: *"Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."* - check [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Try to don't named your project folder as react-bootstrap